# RenderTransfromOrigin vs RotateTransfrom Center Point

Tags: wpf, transform, render

I was wondering what is the difference between RenderTransformOrigin and the center property of the RotateTransfrom. If you apply set a RotateTransform as RenderTransfrom with some value for RenderTransfromOrigin (say 0.5, 0.5 the center of the element) what is the point/effect of setting the center point of the RotateTransfrom? Does that override the RenderTransfromOrigin value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RenderTransformOrigin` applies to whatever transform is applied, further it is relative, i.e. 0.5 means 50% whereas the center of a `RotateTransform` is absolute, 0.5 would mean 0.5 pixels.

You can use both, they will both apply. The value of the tranform's center will be added to the origin set by the `RenderTransformOrigin`.

Comment: So suppose I had an element with width and height of 50, then it would be the same if I set the `RenderTransformOrigin` to .5 .5 or the center to 25,25? But then what would the effect be if I set both? That was my original question. Thank you.

Comment: @mihajlv: Both apply and the center is shifted to the lower right corner (25 in both directions from the origin which is at (25;25) because of the `RenderTransformOrigin`).